# javascript parameter in localisation string

Tags: javascript

We are using strings for localisation support.

1. Some of these have parameters for eg.
   "My name is {0} and I am version {1}.0."
2. Another scenario is we have broken strings like
   "My blah blah is "+
   "Yada Yada ..."+
   "Tom, Harry ... are all pals"

Would these cause problems if we have to translate these to languages like japanese and chinese ?

Please note we have frequent releases and the translation guys id both as requiring much effort for every release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using substitutions like `{0}` is often preferable because of word ordering.

To give a trivial example, the translation of something like "Please save the file" from English into German might look like "Please the file save".  In that case the English string might be:

```
"Please {0} {1}"
```

while the German can be

```
"Bitte {1} {0}"
```

(Forgive my poor knowledge of German, but you get the idea!)  In both cases the code can be:

```
do_substitution(text, verb, object);
```